# Unity fungus got red line

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image: 1]

I got a problem Having the fungus plugin red line
But in unity editor it works normal.
It is a little problem but i want to fix it.

Can someone help?

I try to check visual studio install for VS 2019 has already got unity plugin.
And I try to use open c# project from unity editor
but it still got the problem

```cs
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using Fungus;

    public class TestVariablefungus : MonoBehaviour
    {
      public Flowchart flowchart;
      public int missioncount = 0;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
    public void setFungusmission(int count)
    {
        //flowchart.SetBooleanVariable("missioncomplete", true);
        missioncount= count;
        flowchart.SetIntegerVariable("mission", missioncount);
    }
    public void setGrabMission(bool IsGrab)
    {
        flowchart.SetBooleanVariable("grabOnhand", IsGrab);
    }

   
    
    }
```

Comment: Please include the code inside your question using code snippet

Comment: ok I will change it

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem myself.
That is because I put the project folder under a lot of level of folder.
Make the fungus package cannot catch the function.